# finds occurrences of letter say "m" in the string entered by user and replace it with say “a” and write string to page

Tags: javascript, html

I am taking string input from user.
I am also asking user to enter the letter to replace and also asking user to enter the letter to replaced with.I am using replace function.***please help.thank you!***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=prompt("enter name");
    var b=prompt("enter letter to  replace ");
    var c=prompt("enter the letter to replaced");
    var n = a.length;
    document.write("string:- "+a+"<br>");
    document.write("word to be replace :-"+b+"<br>");
    document.write("word to be replaced with:-"+c+"<br>");
    document.write(n);
    for(i=0;i<=a.length;i++){
    var d=a.replace(c,b);
    }
    document.write(d);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't mention your issue?

Comment: Problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, you can achieve this by using a regular expression for the character to be replaced.

You can create the regular expression as follows:

```
new RegExp(b,"gi")
```

This will create a regular expression for the character you need to replace and the `gi` flag will make it global, ie: it does not stop at first match and case-insensitive.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var a=prompt("enter name");
var b=prompt("enter letter to  replace ");
var c=prompt("enter the letter to replaced");
var n = a.length;
document.write("string:- "+a+"<br>");
document.write("word to be replace :-"+b+"<br>");
document.write("word to be replaced with:-"+c+"<br>");
document.write(n);
var d = a.replace(new RegExp(b,"gi"),c)
document.write(d);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @RiaJain happy it helped